# REGEX Portugal Postal Validation

Tags: regex, validation

I have the following REGEX valdation rule:

```
AND ( 
ISPICKVAL( Account.Country_Code__c ,"Portugal"), 
NOT( 
REGEX( Account.Zip_Postal_Code__c , "\\d{4}(-\\d{3})?")) 
)
```

I want it to validate to make sure that the user enters in the postal code for Portugal as follows: ####-###. Right now it will accept #### OR ####-###. I want it to only accept ####-###, and not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you want is:

```
AND ( 
ISPICKVAL( Account.Country_Code__c ,"Portugal"), 
NOT( 
REGEX( Account.Zip_Postal_Code__c , "^\\d{4}-\\d{3}$")) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Saraiva! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Tranquilo. Mas também é preciso perceber como é que as coisas funcionam. :)

Comment: considering a valid Portuguese postal code has to start with a number greater than 1 we could do: `[1-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}`.